# Getting null values when I did put something inside the input field

Tags: apex, visualforce

So I have made this very simple Visualforce page. Code is as below:

**Controller**:

```
public class UkInternalOrderFormController 
{
    public Contact curContact {get; set;}

    public UkInternalOrderFormController()
    {
        curContact = new Contact();
    }

    public PageReference testFieldValues()
    {
        System.debug('First Name is: ' + curContact.FirstName);

        return null;
    }
    //...
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="UkInternalOrderFormController" tabStyle="UK_Order__c" sidebar="false">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="UK Order Form" subtitle="New UK Order"/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageMessages/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="UK Order Edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!testFieldValues}" value="Submit Order" immediate="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Your Details" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!curContact.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!curContact.LastName}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

When I click the button I read null from the curContact's first name field. And I am feeling very confused about this.

inputField should be two-way binding in my opinion and why is this not working?

Comment: Why do you have immediate=true .Note with immediate=true setters do not run

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I guess that is probably the reason... This code is only for proof of concept. My original code is an actionFunction which fires when a field is set and then the related information will be populated. And during that actionFunction I don't want to check all the mandatory fields prior to that. That is the reason.

Comment: use inputtext then on those fields and avoid inputfield .With immediate=true your setters wont run at all and thats as per design .Usually immediate=true is used for cancel buttons where you don't want validations and all .

Comment: If you really want to exclude required field on submit look into action region. It may or may not help you use case

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thank you for your suggestions. But how can handle the situation for a required lookup relationship field?

Comment: I guess you can use actionRegion to allow only certain components to send to server during action function or Rerender .I think if you throw some example code community might be able to assist .

Comment: Thank you for that. I have learnt a lot in this case! @MohithShrivastava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with immediate=true , the setters are not executed .

Just change the below line and you should see the value in logs

```
<apex:page controller="UkInternalOrderFormController" tabStyle="UK_Order__c" sidebar="false">
<apex:sectionHeader title="UK Order Form" subtitle="New UK Order"/>
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="UK Order Edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!testFieldValues}" value="Submit Order" /> <!--Changed here to remove immediate-->
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Your Details" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!curContact.FirstName}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!curContact.LastName}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```